# I factory reset my SM-A300FU with TWRP and lost access to Play Store

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google

I factory reset my SM-A300FU with TWRP and I can't access Play Store as it says: "Checking info..." then it says:

[image]

Comment: Since you already went ahead and did a factory reset, ever considered just flashing factory firmware via Odin? This will reset the phone to its "working as intended" state, and unless other factors are at play, you should be out of problems.

Comment: Looks like you have a bad WIFI connection there. Try another network.

Answer (score 0):

At first, we can see you do not have a good internet connection, so that might be the problem. Try getting closer to your access point, connect to another one, or use mobile data.

If this does not fix your problem, you could try flashing [the original firmware of the SM-A300FU](https://samsung-firmware.org/model/SM-A300FU/) with the latest version of [Odin](http://odindownload.com/)

Disclaimer: Neither me nor the Odin developers are responsible for any damage you could cause to your device using this method.